# Is it possible to show primeng tooltip conditionally?

Tags: primeng

I'm using primeng tooltip, and I need to show the tooltip only when the input is invalid. I'm using following code but the tool tip is displayed on hover or on focus.

I have tried using tooltipDisabled and tooltipEvent.

```
<input type="url"  name="url" class="form-control" pattern="(https|http)?://.+" 
                        formControlName="url" [disabled]="flag2" pTooltip="Please enter URL in valid format" 
                          tooltipPosition="left" tooltipEvent="focus">
```

Expected: Tooltip should be displayed only if input box is invalid
Actual: tooltip is displayed on hover or focus

Comment: Are you disabling your text field if its invalid?

Answer (score 2):

So the short answer is: no, you can't.

The long answer is: you can show it programatically, but it will also still display through the only options made available by primeNg - onHover and/or onFocus - unless you remove those interactions from the element.

**Displaying Tooltip programatically**

What you can try and do is force the event that triggers the tooltip on the element on which you have it attached to. There are several ways that can be used to find an element, and that is not your question, but you can find your url input field for example by looking for it on the DOM through its name.

```
var element = document.getElementsByName("url")[0];
```

After whichever validation you have fails, you can use that variable to dispatch the event that triggers the tooltip.

```
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseenter'));
```

When the element is valid you can make the tooltip disappear by also dispatching the appropriate event.

```
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseleave'));
```

As I said above, this will not prevent it from appearing when you hover or focus your input, but it answers your question of how it can be done.

**Workaround to prevent standard behaviour**

In order to not have the tooltip appear whenever the Element is hovered or focused, I suggest that you actually attach it to another element alltogether. One that you can create and connect right next to your input field, or in it. The important thing is that it is not the field itself that you want to interact with. And then you can use CSS and add to the element with the tooltip no mouse events, for example through a class.

```
.noPointerEvents {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will ensure that the user won't activate the tooltip with the mouse. And it will only trigger through the previousl given code. You can also disable tabbing, if you selected one element that can be tabbed through.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack. But it is a hack and I would not recommend this. Since primeng doesn't expose any way to control the tooltip you have to do it by accessing the element manually. Following is one way to do this.

1. Add two classes to the tooltip using tooltipStyleClass, one class `d-none` which has `display:none !important;` property and other class `random-class` to access the element using jquery or javascript. Using jQuery we will access the element and remove class `d-none` when the input is invalid. This check has to be implemented in `(focus) = 'onFocus()'` function.
2. In the `onFocus` function remove the `d-none` class from the tooltip element if the input field is invalid. If the input field is valid then add the `d-none` class to the element

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" pInputText pTooltip="Enter your username" placeholder="Right" tooltipStyleClass="d-none random-class" tooltipEvent="focus" (focus)="onFocus()">
```

**CSS**

```
.d-none {
    display: none !important;
}
```

**Javascript/Component**

```
onFocus() {
    if (//input field invalid) {    
        setTimeout(() => {
            $('.random-class').removeClass('d-none');
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

I cannot stress enough on the fact that this is a hack, I do not recommend this but it gets the job done. If you want to replicate this on other input fields then every field should have different random class name to access that specific element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can leverage the input directive using a conditional. You can use this pattern for all input directives.

```
<button type="submit" [pTooltip]="active ? 'I am active' : null">
   pTooltip Button
</button>
```