# How to show primeng tooltip only on click?

Tags: angular, tooltip, primeng

I am trying to show the tooltip only on the click, so by default I disabled the tooltip, and when I click on the span I re enable the tooltip.

But the tooltip doesn't show, I have to move out my mouse and then move my mouse hover the span.

Here is my html template

```html
<span (click)="onClick()" [tooltipDisabled]="tooltipDisabled" pTooltip="My tooltip"
      tooltipPosition="top">My text</span>
```

And here is my typescript

```
export class MyComponent {

  tooltipDisabled = true;

  constructor() {

  }

  onClick() {
    this.tooltipDisabled = false;
  }
}
```

I also tried to dispatch and event based on [the answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66797762/10270107) but it doesn't work either.

**Is there a solution to show the tooltip on my click ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To only show the tooltip on click, I changed the component to access the directive from it. The directive is pTooltip but the class of the directive is Tooltip, [based on the github sources](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/tooltip/tooltip.ts).

I was able to access the directive by a ViewChild `@ViewChild(Tooltip) tooltip!: Tooltip;`. And then inside the onclick method it's possible to call the activate method of the directive.

So the component is like this:

```js
export class MyComponent {

  @ViewChild(Tooltip) tooltip!: Tooltip;

  constructor() {

  }

  onClick() {
    this.tooltip.activate();
  }
}
```

And to prevent the tooltip from showing on hover I changed the `tooltipEvent`and added a life of 1 second so that the tooltip hide after some times.

```html
<span (click)="onClick()" [life]="1000" tooltipEvent="focus" pTooltip="My tooltip"
      tooltipPosition="top">My text</span>
```

Comment: If we have multiple input with different tooltips, how to make a difference between them ?

Comment: Since it's a custom component you can create your own logic in it. For example the component can be `CustomTooltipComponent` with some inputs (ex: tooltiptext, duration etc...). Then with theses inputs you can reference it inside the `pTooltip` like that `[pTooltip]="tooltiptext"`, where `tooltiptext`is the name of your @Input property. Maybe you could also create your own directive.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for multiple tooltips:

1. Mark your "tooltiped" ~inputs with id:

```html
<p-chips id="myId" [(ngModel)]="model" pTooltip="Hello world"></p-chips>
```

2. Use `ViewChildren` instead of `ViewChild` to find all tooltips in your component and filter them by ID:

```js
import { QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
export class MyComponent {

    @ViewChildren(Tooltip) tooltips!: QueryList <Tooltip>;

    constructor() {

    }

    /**
    * finds tooltip by its id
    */
    private findTooltipById(searchId: string): Tooltip | undefined {
        return this.tooltips.find(tooltip => tooltip.el.nativeElement.id === searchId);
    }

    onClick() {
        const foundTooltip = this.findTooltipById('myId');
        if (foundTooltip) {
            foundTooltip.activate();
        }
    }
}
```

It is not perfect solution, but it works ;-)

Comment: it is not work form me on PrimeNg v 14 . but is is nice approch

Comment: @yehonatanyehezkel This code is used in production by me under PrimeNg 14.2.2 and works fine...

Comment: this line in the end look like a mistake "this.foundTooltip.activate();" - foundTooltip dont have this

Comment: @yehonatanyehezkel yes, you are right, this removed...